# Controlling the 5V pin on the Arduino nano 33 BLE

Tags: arduino-nano-ble

Following the guidance on [this post](https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/360014779679-About-Nano-boards-with-disabled-5-V-pins?_gl=1*1yxmaf9*_ga*NjU4MDE0NTY2LjE2NjQyOTI4MjA.*_ga_NEXN8H46L5*MTY2NDI5MjgyMC4xLjEuMTY2NDI5NTc2NS4wLjAuMA..)  I have enabled the 5V pin.  That same post suggests that I control that pin with D12, though I find it weird since there is already a D12 pin.  When I try and run some code the D12 pin is performing exactly as I expect, but the 5V pin is doing nothing.

Looking through the [tech specs](https://docs.arduino.cc/static/741bbe6b7ce4563049b3b662180471c3/ABX00030-datasheet.pdf) it says "**the 5V pin does NOT supply voltage but is rather connected, through a jumper, to the USB power input.**" which I find odd, since if its connected to the power input, should it not be supplying voltage?

Could someone clarify if its possible to use the 5V pin like a digital pin, and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Following the guidance on this post I have enabled the 5V pin. That same post suggests that I control that pin with D12, though I find it weird since there is already a D12 pin. When I try and run some code the D12 pin is performing exactly as I expect, but the 5V pin is doing nothing.

5 V pin is the the 12th pin of the PCB

> Looking through the tech specs it says "the 5V pin does NOT supply voltage but is rather connected, through a jumper, to the USB power input." which I find odd, since if its connected to the power input, should it not be supplying voltage?

it says that the 5V pin is connected to the USB power input through a jumper and the jumper is not connected from factory

Comment: `the 5V pin does NOT supply voltage but is rather connected, through a jumper, to the USB power input` could mean that the pin is not a power input for the arduino

Comment: @jsotola it can be both because it is connected to USB power input and to the 5 V to 3.3 V regulator which powers the rest of the board. but the pads are not connected to prevent using the 5 V pin without a solder bridge. https://content.arduino.cc/assets/NANO33BLE_V4.0_sch.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but it does not answer the question.  Is it possible to use the 5V pin like a digital pin?  If so, how?

Comment: @Pablo, the pin is just on a 5 V rail of the board. there is no logic, just 5 V power.